# event listener working with getElementByID but not with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

as per the post title, I have these scripts:

```
let campolim = document.getElementById("province");

campolim.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  if (campolim.value.length > 3) {
    campolim.value = campolim.value.slice(0, 3);
  }
});
//----------------------------------------------------//
let campilim = document.querySelectorAll("limitme");
for (var i = 0; i < campilim.length; i++) {
  campilim[i].addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if (campolim[i].value.length > 3) {
      campolim[i].value = campolim[i].value.slice(0, 3);
    }
  });
}
```

The scripts should do the same thing (limit the input filds to 3 chars). The first one is working properly, but if I want to capture all fields with *limitme* class, the script returns that cannot find the length of a unknown element.

Why? What am I missing?
This is the html:

```
<input type="text" class="limitme form-input" id="province" name="province" value="" placeholder="provincia" required="">

<input type="text" class="limitme form-input" id="cap" name="cap" value="" placeholder="cap" required="">

<input type="submit" >
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `document.querySelectorAll("limitme")` supposed to get? An element with the ID of `limitme`? The class of `limitme`? An element named `limitme`? Your syntax is incorrect. Maybe you wanted `document.querySelectorAll(".limitme")`?

Comment: All elements with class "limitme". I noticed that the scripts does not work even with document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: To specify class selector with `querySelectorAll()`, you need to use dot `.` before the class name, so `".limitme"` not `"limitme"`.

Comment: Just a typo: `campolim[i]` instead of `campilim[i]` -> vote to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was just a typo in campilim (campolim)

```
let campolim = document.getElementById("province");

campolim.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  if (campolim.value.length > 3) {
    campolim.value = campolim.value.slice(0, 3);
  }
});
//----------------------------------------------------//
let campilim = document.querySelectorAll(".limitme");
console.log(campilim)
for (let i = 0; i < campilim.length; i++) {
  campilim[i].addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    if (campilim[i].value.length > 3) {
      campilim[i].value = campilim[i].value.slice(0, 3);
    }
  });
}
```

The code works fine with typo fixed.

Comment: thanks, you all get it right...lots of typos. I must have been very tyred. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

u replace second section of your code with

```js
 let campilim = document.querySelectorAll(".limitme");
            for (var i = 0; i < campilim.length; i++) {
                campilim[i].addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
                   let element=e.currentTarget;
                    if (element.value.length > 3) {
                        element.value = element.value.slice(0, 3);
                    }
                });
            }
```

when use addEventListener in input parameter send e for event and use in function for detect change . for find what is source element  u must use e.currentTarget code.